# Connect external web app to wordpress

Tags: api, http-api

We have a web app that will allow users to edit their videos; and add intros,  outros, and watermarks. Once the user already done on their video. We need to provide an option to post or syndicate their video as a draft on their WordPress site.

Our plan is to create a WordPress plugin that the user needs to install on their WordPress site. But our problem are the following:

1. How can we authenticate our web app to the user's WordPress page?
2. Looking int HTTP API most of the options are only for retrieving contents. Is there also a way to create pages?

Comment: I am also looking for this, do you have an answer already?

Comment: I've just started playing around with phonegap to pull data from Wordpress.
I'm using the JSON API plugin here: http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api
On top of the core functionality for retrieving posts, there are options to create/update/delete, but this must be enabled in the admin.
It's not a complete answer, but it could be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

There's the [XML RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) - the Remote *Posting* Protocol - that is already in use by WP.org [Applications](http://wordpress.org/mobile/). What you're searching for is [`wp.newPost`](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API). The API is extensible.

The URL for the XML RPC is

```
http://example.com/xmlrpc.php
```

To send data to WP, use [`xmlrpc_encode_request()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlrpc-encode-request.php) where the first argument would be `wp.newPost` and second one your arguments for the post.